# Azure Active Directory B2C restrict login from another device

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to restrict the user login from two different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure AD B2C cannot do this.

I understand why do you need this. But I think **it should be configured in your Application ,not Azure AD B2C.** For example, you can let your Application get the users' deviceIDs and restrict them can login from one device.

Actually, Azure AD B2C can do cloud identity management, so it cannot collect more information from users. For the security and private policy, Azure AD B2C may not have very powerful features.

Hope this helps!